# converting xml into array, unable to handle node inside a node

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml, associative-array

I want to convert a xml script into a associative array in PHP. The XML script is :

```
<ages>
    <Peter>
        <Peterchild>4</Peterchild>
        <Peterchild>6</Peterchild>
    </Peter>
    <Quagmire>30</Quagmire>
    <Joe>34</Joe>
</ages>
```

and the code i wrote for converting it to an array is

```
${$xml->getName()} = array();
foreach($xml->children() as $child){
    $ages[$child->getName()] = (string)$child;
}
```

which gives the output as

```
Array
(
    [Peter] => 



    [Quagmire] => 30
    [Joe] => 34
)
```

The problem is that I am unable to figure out a condition to recursively traverse through the children of children (children of Peter in this example). How to I change this code to consider those nodes as well?

Comment: You said the magic word, recursively.... recursion. With the current use of your method children(), you'll need to apply a recursive function to drill down and get the values you want. That or you should investigate if there is another method for just turning the entire xml into an array or array of arrays if needed.

Comment: See 2 examples on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php, both do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a function that parses one level, then have the function call itself when it finds a node inside the current level.  It's pretty complex and can get messy.  Out of curiosity, why would you do this when you can access all the information you need in object format using a SimpleXML object?

Answer (score 0):

```
${$xml->getName()} = array();
    foreach($xml->children() as $child) 
    {
      if (count($child->children() > 0) 
      {
         foreach ($child->children as $childnode)
         {
           $ages[$childnode->getName()] = (string)$childnode;
         }
      }
      else {
          $ages[$child->getName()] = (string)$child;
      }
   }
```

This will only work if it is 1 level deep, if it is going to be more levels you should write a function, that will cycle through it level by level.